# Why not Reading c++ file on android studio on my app..?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-ndk

I have my c++ file I putted it in jni folder with application.mk ,android.mk and putted everything in build.gradle and in the class with native stringtoJNI and static {} i guess i putted everything and still I have issues when I tried helloJNI sample it worked but on my app there is problem i searched alot and saw similar issues and tried almost everything and still i get error.

ndktest.c

```
jstring Java_com_example_mike_lol8_WallService(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
jstring str = "http://555.555.555.555";
return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, str); }
```

Application.mk

```
APP_ABI := all
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

 include $(CLEAR_VARS)

   LOCAL_MODULE := ndktest
  LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ndktest.c

 include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

build.gradle

```
 ndk {
        moduleName "ndktest"
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs "src/main/jni"
         jniLibs.srcDir "src/main/jniLibs"
    }
}
```

WallService.class

```
public class WallService extends Service {
  public static native String stringFromJNI();

private static String BASEURL = stringFromJNI();
static {
    System.loadLibrary("ndktest");
}
```

So in so examples StringJNI reading the file but i got error in the logcat but this is my code StringJNI it's red can't connect with my file(can't see it)
so maybe someone can help me

Comment: UnsatisfiedLinkError is the error in  the logCat

Comment: Android studio version?

Comment: 2.2.2 i guess it's the latest version

Comment: can you place your complete method /flow you are calling to native method

Comment: EDITED.!! its not method it is at the beginning of my service ( my service is post request to my server and get response and put this response into wallpaper (wallpaperservice).)

Comment: wallservice You are using the wrong library to load library (hello-jni).

Comment: System.loadLibrary("ndktest");  System.loadLibrary("hello-jni"); both are different

Comment: yes yes sry my bad i edited wrong ..!

Comment: You mention C++ both in the title and in your question, but as far as I can tell you're using C, not C++. They are two separate languages.

Comment: Anyway, update your question with the full code for `ndktest.c` and `WallService.java`, as well as the full logcat error message. Also, check whether `libndktest.so` actually has been built, and for which ABI(s).

Comment: ndktest is full  - wallservice this matters about native language  it is the beginning of the code and not somewhere else i wrote something about native code

Comment: _"ndktest is full"_ Doesn't look like it to me. For example, you don't include `jni.h`. _"wallservice this matters about native language it is the beginning of the code"_ The package name (which you haven't shown) is highly relevant, especially since you said that you were getting an `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

Comment: dude u want from me to write #include <jni.h>
#include <string>
 lol  thanks anyways i solved my problem and answer it so maybe I can be useful to others .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution (maybe people benefit from it ) thanks all for the help

```
public class WallService extends Service {

public native String stringFromJNI();
static {
    System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
}
```

scr/main/cpp or(jni)/native-lib.c

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

extern "C"
 jstring
Java_com_example_mike_lol10_WallService_stringFromJNI(
    JNIEnv *env,
    jobject /* this */) {
std::string hello = "http://130.193.127.250";
return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
   }
```

build.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.mike.lol10"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
        }
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}
}
```

**or u can check the support c++ when your creating new project under the name .
It create Cmakelist too.**

Answer (score 0):

A) You need to add dependency into the build.Gradle file.gradle-experimental

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.8.2'
}
```

There are two build files. 
1) app.gradle
2) project.gradle. (Change into this file)

B) ndk build script

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model{
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 17
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.drawerlayouttest"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel 17
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 17

        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'))
            }
        }

        ndk{
            moduleName "myjni"
            cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
            ldLibs.addAll(["GLESv2","log"])
            stl "gnustl_shared"
        }

        /*sourceSets.main {
            jni.srcDirs = []
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }*/
    }
}
```

Comment: i cant sync i have error(could not get unknown property'cppFlages' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.NdkOptions

Comment: @Dr.Easy you are using wrong package name. post your code with another question.